# iPhone SDK: Freezing part of a webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I was wondering if there was a way to freeze a certain section of a webview so that when you scroll through the webview that part of the webview still shows instead of hiding. For example, When having facebook in a webview how could it be possible to keep the blue bar with the notifications, messages, and friend request to always stay on the top when scrolling down the webview just like it is done in the facebook app?

Comment: not sure if this is even possible

Comment: Well it was done in the facebook app... or how did they do it?

Comment: Are you writing this website yourself?  In that case that is easy.  Otherwise, it would be a real hack to make it happen.  The facebook app is a native app, not a website displayed in a `UIWebView` - they use a `UINavigationBar`, not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a element inside the webview stays pinned on the screen without affected by the scrolling, you may try to apply *position:fixed* CSS style on that DOM element.

Please note that *position:fixed* is not supported before iOS5.

And the native scroll bouncing effect of the UIWebView also affects the fixed position DOM element so you may determine if you also need to disable that bouncing effect.